# Weebly Websites SEO

Tags: seo, weebly

From what I understand Weebly uses the drag and drop interface and even when looking at the code, it doesn't show the full content, but rather shows {content} which is where the drag and drop parts of the content are put.

Does their drag and drop content, such as text have the same effect as a `<p>` or `<h1>` tag would on a website? Is the weebly drag and drop less optimized for SEO?

Does using Weebly have an adverse affect on SEO compared with building from scratch if I do include keywords, alternate text etc...?

Comment: The *{content}* is a variable. I have no idea how it wraps this variable if you drag and drop. You can create a page, drag and drop some text into it and then view the page source. I would assume that it parses the paragraphs and wraps each in a paragraph tag. It might place a div tag around the entire dropped text block. There may be variables you can place in the text to create header tags and so forth. You may have to read the documentation to know (aka RTM or RTFM if you have a sense of humor). I do not know Weebly. Perhaps someone else will.

Comment: It looks as though all text is in <span> tags with no <p> tags. Would that have an adverse effect?

Comment: No it should not. I forgot about span. That make sense. Just for mark-up, you may be able to put tags in your text then drag and drop. That is probably what the were intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google crawls weebly website just like any other website.

- If you have proper back links pointing to your Website and have optimized your website for the keywords. It will rank like any other website.
- You should make sure that you are using proper HTML tags h1,h2,h3,title,p etc,.
- Some times you may give large font size to a `<p></p>` and use it as Headings or sub headings. That will certainly effecct your SEO.

Things that you can take in account while making weebly website:

- You have the option to add H1,H2,H3 tags etc,. in basic HTML editor.
- Cross check whether the *drag and drop* paragraphs, Headings and titles are having proper tags. (Checking the source of your website after publishing will help.)
- Alt tag can be used to optimize images that you upload.
- Adding links: Since link pointing from your website will also effect your SEO. No follow links should be added. If you do not have an option to place no-follow links by *drag and drop*. It is better to add them by doping `Html Code` and placing the links in it.
- If you need more control on your website I suggest using WordPress. Though Weebly do not have any adverse effect on your SEO.

Comment: I did notice Weebly uses <span> tags for text but other than that, I'm just using the add html widget for my heading tags